# Prolog facts value to list

Tags: prolog

```
facts
    nondeterm li(char).
clauses
 li('a').
 li('b').
 li('c').

save("D:\\Dlist.txt").

goal
consult("D:\\Dlist.txt"),
```

How to create list with value [a,b,c].

iam use [Visual Prolog 5.2 Personal Edition]

Comment: In a real Prolog, `findall(X, li(X), Xs)` would unify Xs with [a,b,c] and you would be done, but unfortunately, you're using something very weird and nonstandard and I can't say for sure that it will work. If _you_ chose Visual Prolog, I recommend you backtrack ;) and try again.

Comment: thank  , it work good :D